# GRASS GIS i.landsat.toar hangs & holds CPU at 100%

Tags: python, grass-gis

I use python scripting to automate processing of several Landsat 8 scenes.

I use a VPS (4 core, 8GB memory, SSD) running Ubuntu 14.04 with GRASS 7.0.1

Line in script for i.landsat.toar:

```
grass.run_command('i.landsat.toar', input='b', output='rb', metfile='/home/ben/map/working/%s_MTL.txt' % scene, sensor='oli', method='dos4', pixel='1000')
```

Usually this works flawlessly but on occasion (1 in 100) when calculating dark pixel the script will just hang endlessly in some sort of loop.

I added a timer function so that if it hangs for more than 15 min it will raise error and move onto the next scene. That works for now but even when I restart the server and download the Landsat scenes again I still get the same error. I also run GRASS 7 on a Windows 2008 server but do not have the same problem with exact same scene.

Curiously even when it works it still leaves the command open. When opening htop I often have 3 or 4 i.landsat.toar commands still running taking 100% CPU of each core.

Is this a known problem? I had a quick search of known bugs and couldnt find anything.

Update: still no solution to problem. The same scenes keep causing this problem.

Comment: Please check the output of g.region -p, does this match the image extent and region?

Comment: I set the region using the band 8 tif so should match.